# VBA excel programming : Dumping data from one sheet to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

`
Option Explicit

Sub MoveToSheet()
     Range("A2:A9").Select

```
 If Range("A2:A9").Value = "1" Then

 Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B9").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:A9")

 Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
End If
```

End Sub `[image: output sheet]

[image: The sheet from which data has to be dumped.]

There is an excel sheet with ItemId and ItemName.For a single ItemID there are 4-5 ItemName.The data from this sheet needs to be dumped into another sheet using VBA Excel Programming.
The sheet in which the data is dumped shall list the ItemName in different columns for a single ItemId.

Comment: SO is not a code for me site.  Please show your attempts and explain what is going wrong, so we might address the specific problem in your code.

Comment: You can check the code.Have started using this technology yesterday itself,so ain't well acquainted. the code says there is type-mismatch error :(

Answer (score 0):

You get the Type mismatch error because you are trying to get a value from a range of cells `Range("A2:A9").Value` and I think this syntax will work only for a single cell, like `Range("A2").Value`. Then you have a `Do...Loop` which will loop until the last row of the spreasheet because there is no condition check.

Please, can you try this subroutine? You can place it in a module and call it from the VBA editor or link it to a button. I assume your items are sorted by itemID.

```
Sub copyItems()
  Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

  ' This will clear your destination worksheet. Change the range to your needs
  Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:Z999").ClearContents

  Dim itemID As Integer, startRow As Integer, endRow As Integer
  startRow = 2

  Do
    itemID = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(startRow, 1)
    endRow = startRow + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), itemID) - 1
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:A" & endRow - startRow + 2).Offset(0, itemID - 1).Value = _
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & startRow & ":B" & endRow).Value
    startRow = endRow + 1
  Loop While Cells(startRow, 1).Value <> ""
End Sub
```

You should see your items placed in different columns in Sheet3 (Column A for itemID=1, column B for itemID=2 and so on)

New routine to catch alphanumeric ItemIDs

```
Sub copyItems2()
  Dim itemID As String, startRow As Integer, endRow As Integer, itemNum As Integer
  Dim source As String, destination As String

  startRow = 2
  itemNum = 1
  source = "Sheet1"
  destination = "Sheet3"

  Sheets(source).Activate

  ' This will clear your destination worksheet. Change the range to your needs
  Sheets(destination).Range("A2:Z999").ClearContents

  Do
    itemID = Sheets(source).Cells(startRow, 1)
    endRow = startRow + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets(source).Range("A:A"), itemID) - 1
    Sheets(destination).Range("A2:A" & endRow - startRow + 2).Offset(0, itemNum - 1).Value = _
      Sheets(source).Range("B" & startRow & ":B" & endRow).Value
    startRow = endRow + 1
    itemNum = itemNum + 1
  Loop While Cells(startRow, 1).Value <> ""
End Sub
```

This one should handle also alphanumeric codes.

Comment: Ya it works fine :) Thankyou so much. But when I am changing the Sheet3 to Sheet4  in this line  of code (Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:Z999").ClearContents) it shows error "Subscript out of range".

Comment: Rading the code you posted I thought that Sheet1 is the source worksheet and Sheet3 is the destination worksheet. Please, can you tell me what they are called? If I try to change it in my spreadsheet I get the same error, but I have no Sheet4 in there...

Comment: Also I want to know what if the itemId is a string like "AS_100" INSTEAD OF  "1" .How does the increment thing will work then ? :O

Comment: I am sorry, but if itemID is a string it will not work this way. I am adding a new routine (copyItems2) which should do the work.

Comment: What is itemNum ? Also can you please explain what is this code of line doing??? "endRow = startRow + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets(source).Range("A:A"), itemID) - 1
    Sheets(destination).Range("A2:A" & endRow - startRow + 2).Offset(0, itemNum - 1).Value = _
      Sheets(source).Range("B" & startRow & ":B" & endRow).Value"

Comment: itemNum is an arbitrary numeric code I assign to itemID, so if itemID is not a number, itemNum will still be a number and I can use it to shift pasting of values of (`itemNum-1`) columns right of column A. The line `endRow = ...` uses `startRow` which is the first row where a given itemID appears (in a sorted spreadsheet) and the `countif` function to get how many rows are assigned to that particular itemID,so endRow is the last row with that itemID.

Comment: The line `Sheets(destination).Range...endRow).Value` is a single line of code spread over two lines of the VBA editor by ` _`. It takes a range of cells one column wide and `endRow - startRow` rows wide and copies that from the source to the destination worksheet (same size).

Comment: In the Destination sheet,when I give range as Range("C11:AD148"),it gives error subscript out of range. I want to dump the data from C column to AD column and from 11th row. What is the issue then ?

Comment: Please, can you tell me exactly how  you are trying to use it? your comment is not much clear.

Comment: I had reposted the question.Can you check please?